# /etc/resolv.conf on CentOS7 doesn't seem to honor options

Tags: linux, centos, dns, networkmanager, nslookup

```
# uname -a
Linux myserver 3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 17 23:49:17 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)


# cat /etc/resolv.conf

# Generated by NetworkManager
options rotate
options timeout:3
options attempts:6
nameserver one.xxx.xxx.xxx
nameserver two.xxx.xxx.xxx
nameserver thr.xxx.xxx.xxx


# nslookup some.url.ihave
Server:     one.xxx.xxx.xxx
Address:    one.xxx.xxx.xxx#53

** server can't find some.url.ihave: NXDOMAIN
```

Why does it not try the other two nameservers for DNS lookup that I have entered in resolv.conf ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ** server can't find some.url.ihave: NXDOMAIN
> ```

`nslookup` stops because it has received an answer to its query.  It stops asking once it has an answer, obviously.  That answer was that the domain does not exist.

If you don't want that to be the case, do not list in `resolv.conf` the IP address of a DNS server that thinks that that domain does not exist.  Otherwise you'll end up sometimes, perhaps always, getting that as the answer.  (*There is no fixed universal rule* about what order these things are tried in.  Two programs from the same stable, `nslookup` and the BIND DNS client library from ISC, use different orders; and there are other DNS clients from other people with other behaviours still.)

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2003). *[Your fallback proxy DNS servers must provide the same view of the DNS namespace as your principal one.](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/dns-client-all-proxies-must-provide-same-service.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2003). *[Why the results from `nslookup` are different to the operation of `ping`](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/nslookup-results-different-to-ping.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2001). *[`nslookup` is a badly flawed tool. Don't use it.](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/nslookup-flaws.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: Great answer. thanks!

Comment: The link says it all.